# How to make my C++ library compliant with IEEE 754

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, numeric, ieee-754

I have written a small library (in C++11) to compute with quaternions, but I quickly realized there are many precision/accuracy issues given that quite a few floating point operations are involved. That led me to looking at std::complex and IEEE 754. std::complex does a fair amount of work dealing with NaNs in particular. Is that the only thing I need to worry about to become "IEEE 754 compliant"? More generally, is there a "recipe" for how to turn an otherwise naive numerical library into one that would be "IEEE 754 compliant"?

**Note**: the problem is not about whether the compiler is IEEE 754, but about whether I should take special steps in my own algorithms to satisfy IEEE 754. After all, I am in the same position as whoever wrote std::complex, and they did take extra steps, e.g. for NaNs.

Comment: Side note: if you care about speed be aware of [poor performance of `std::complex`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=he-XVt1xIE0)

Comment: Thanks! Indeed - so I'm planning to make IEEE 754 conformance optional. But a paper from Intel (of course!) warned me of crashing rockets and more if my lib was not IEEE-754.

Comment: Quaternion operations (like multiplication) often deal with running sums of (signed) products. You could look at [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) as a relatively inexpensive way to improve accuracy with IEEE-754 compliance. You could also look at a relatively mature implementation like Boost's quaternion class. I imagine complex concepts like branch cuts, etc., get a whole lot stranger in a theoretical sense with quaternions, if you want to be consistent.

Comment: Also note that if you're using quaternions for rotations, you should (re)normalize them after applying operations, to keep them as 'unit' rotations.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check your library's Header `<limits>` constant `numeric_limits::is_iec559` (IEC 559 is the same as IEEE 754) to see whether or not your C++ compiler already supports IEEE 754.

Comment: Paul - yes, indeed, but that doesn't seem to be the end of the story. If you take a look at the std::complex library for example, it has code to handle NaNs - so I thought that as a programmer, I had to add similar code wherever my algorithms can produce NaNs.

Answer (score 0):

Making the arithmetic IEEE-compliant is not your task but that of the compiler.

Your compiler either is or is not IEEE-compliant (@Paul) and you can do nothing much about it. Specifically, you cannot write a non-IEEE compliant program using an IEEE-compliant compiler double arithmetic (please don't take me at my word here :) ). This is just similar as you can hardly write a non-ISO/IEC 14882:2011-comliant program with an ISO/IEC 14882:2011-comliant compiler.

This however does not secure that the program gives an expected output and it is free of weird operations, including UB. And that is similar to where NaNs and INFs come into play in IEEE 754. They are there to give a “reasonable answer” to not well defined mathematical operations such 0/0 or out of range operations such as 1/0.

The standard does not care of how you treat these answers in your library (i.e. how you translate them to the lib user). The standard only specifies a way of how using these “reasonable answers” in yet another mathematical operation gives yet another “reasonable answer”.

You may be interested in http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf (rather tough reading but worth the effort at least for gripping the idea)

Ps I checked my lib < complex > implementation (MinGW 4.9.1. 32bit) and did not notice any NaNs magic there.

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time someone referred to the Goldberg paper as the final word in floating-point questions...

Comment: @PavDub - checkout the gcc implementation of std::complex. I saw some special code for NaNs there. I also saw a presentation from a German guy who complained that this extra processing made his computations - which he could prove would never yield NaNs - too slow.

Comment: @Frank I **haven't** gone through the complex implementation line by line but did not notice any trace of NaNs at a first glance. Could you post me your implementation? Not that I do not believe you but I am just curious... ( mine is here: [link](http://wikisend.com/download/379378/complex.h) )

Comment: I am using the one on the Mac at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/complex.

Comment: I'll post a snippet on pastebin later - I can't access pastebin from work. template<class _Tp>
complex<_Tp>
operator*(const complex<_Tp>& __z, const complex<_Tp>& __w)
 uses a lot of isinf and isnan.

Comment: @Frank Unfortunately, I don't have access to XCode. The snippet would be nice, thanks.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/ZjB3pZTW. It's after seeing that code that I started thinking I needed to do something about IEEE 754 in my own quaternion library :-)

Comment: @Frank so it's as I said _The standard does not care of how you treat these answers in your library (i.e. how you translate them to the lib user)._ The MinGW 4.9.1. 32bit Win implementation does not care about NaNs and INFs at all (Funny is their own comment "XXX: This is a grammar school implementation." in the source code :) ). I added a new answer since it is too long for a short comment...

Answer (score 0):

[@Frank : comments below my last answer Aug 3 at 7:38]

When multiplying comlex numbers, NaN can be a result of - using the notation of XCode iplementation at [uploaded by @Frank - PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/ZjB3pZTW):

```
__x is NaN if any of __a, __b, __c, __d is Nan or
__ac == +INF && __bd == +INF or
__ac == -INF && __bd == -INF or
__a == (+/-)INF && __c == 0 or *vice versa* or
__b == (+/-)INF && __d == 0 or *vice versa* or
    
__y is NaN if any of __a, __b, __c, __d is Nan or
__ad == -INF && __bc == +INF or
__ad == +INF && __bc == -INF or
__a == (+/-)INF && __d == 0 or *vice versa* or
__b == (+/-)INF && __c == 0 or *vice versa* or
```

Then they (XCode STL authors) play around with these to allow for cases such as

```
(INF + INFi)*(c + di)
(INF + INFi)*(0 + 0i)
etc...
```

The trick (most likely) is to set the INFs- and NaNs-containing values to either (+/-)1 or (+/-)0 so that the final recalculation

```
if (__recalc)
{
    __x = _Tp(INFINITY) * (__a * __c - __b * __d);
    __y = _Tp(INFINITY) * (__a * __d + __b * __c);
}
```

results in

```
INF * (+/-)INF = (+/-)INF or
INF * (+/-)0   = NaN
```

as appropriate.

This is the

> how you translate them to the lib user

**ps.>** I do not have time to go so deep into the problem so that I could judge their implementation but it is most likely reasonable. (this [Math forum link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171122124311/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/63359.html) is helpful but I am of no help to readily translate it into the [a+bi] complex numers notation) Anyway, MinGW 4.9.1. 32bit Win implementation leaves this task open and the user should treat the corner cases. You can adopt the MinGW strategy at first or you can take that of XCode if you know how to treat the corner cases of the quaterions algebra properly. In any case this is no longer much about *How to make my C++ library compliant with IEEE 754* ...

Comment: so that was the genesis of this thread: I looked at what they were doing for std::complex, and it got me thinking about whether I should handle all the cases they handle in my own operations, and if that was required to be "IEEE-754 compliant": I thought this standard described what was expected in these corner cases - my mistake then.